# Examples of molecules with D4 and C9 point groups

Tags: physical-chemistry, group-theory

Trying to come up with examples of (hypothetical) molecules/shapes that have $D_4$ and $C_{9h}$ point groups.

For $D_4$, I thought a cyclobutane structure, but with 4 substituents coming off of the ring all pointing in the same direction. However, I'm not sure if this is $D_4$ because in a book I am reading it says that all the $D_n$ point groups show chirality, which this molecule does not.

For $C_{9h}$, I really can't think of any shape/structure that doesn't just end up being $D_{9h}$. $C_9$ would be a 9-bladed propellor shape, although I'm not really sure how to draw this, and I don't see how I could alter that to get $C_{9h}$.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For nearly any point group which is actually feasible (including $D_4$), look up the [Symmetry gallery](http://symmetry.otterbein.edu/gallery). Your all-cis tetra-substituted cyclobutane would be $C_{4v}$, BTW.

As for $C_{9h}$... well, I don't quite believe this is possible, but probably we may come up with something that would look *almost* realistic.

A substituted nanotube fragment will do, I think.
[image: C9h molecule]

Surely it is hypothetical, so what? Cyclo-$\ce{C18}$ is hypothetical as well, and in my opinion, has lower chances to be stable. Also, its symmetry is kinda dubious.

Comment: why is cyclo-C18 hypothetical? wasn't it first observed in 1989? http://science.sciencemag.org/content/245/4922/1088

Comment: **No, it was not.** These guys made some calculations, then prepared some precursors, then saw in the mass spectra some $\ce{C18}$ which is _probably_ cyclic, though nobody knows for sure. That's a circumstantial evidence at best.

Comment: @http://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/500110/pdf maybe you will be more convinced by this 2006 gas phase spectrum, although these author say it is a cumulene ring with alternating bond angles, D9h.

Comment: a 2011 book says "With this correction, the minimum is the cyclo-polyacetylene C9h. However, there is a tendency for HF as well as BLYP to artificially yielding lower symmetry structures. Thus, the most stable structure of the cyclic C18 is still debatable" https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=hu3FCgAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA343&dq=cyclic+c18+c9h&ots=1TUtcWwKlu&sig=5CmIe2xxsGMV6zG24Oq3HJempos#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: OK, well, so this thing does exist, after all. It is its exact geometry (and consequently symmetry) that is hypothetical.

Comment: I'm wondering if anyone tried to make your structure, closest I found is http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja807126u "For [9]cycloparaphenylene, the situation is
slightly more complex. Reduced symmetry due to an odd number of
phenyl rings results in a lowest energy conformation in which the
dihedral angle varies between 18°, 30°, 31°, and 33° around the carbon
nanohoop (Figure 3b)"

Comment: That's another story. Paraphenylene structure is all wobbly; mine is rigid.

Comment: so will it twist less, or not at all? The unsubstituted version of your structure is structure number 180 here http://pubs.rsc.org/en/content/articlehtml/2015/cs/c4cs00366g , but I don't think anyone succeeded in making it yet

Comment: Yes, I believe chances are pretty high that it will not twist. (Not that the molecule would be easy to make, though.)

Answer (score 2):

The cyclo-C18 polyyne is $C_{9h}$ according [Carbon Rich Compounds II: Oligoacetylenes](https://books.google.com/books?id=YWD7CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA46&dq=%22c9h%22%20%22as%20the%20most%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvutKIlJTPAhUK4yYKHbcXBe4Q6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=%22c9h%22%20%22as%20the%20most%22&f=false) at page 46

The molecule is a planar 18-carbon ring with alternating short and long bonds (triple and single bonds) and bond angles alternating between 157 and 163 degrees.

Comment: Isn't it $\ce{D}_{9\ce{h}}$? Forgive me if I am wrong.

Comment: You might want to attach [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eOusN.gif).

Comment: Now that's what I call a stretch. We'll have to tell the difference between $C_{9h}$, $D_{9h}$, and probably other options, based on some minuscule, nearly invisible deviations. In the absence of other options, though, this might do.

Comment: @user34388 it that accurate, or is like scheme 8.4 here: https://books.google.com/books?id=kP99Ee7Qq4oC&pg=PA354&dq=c18+polyyne+c9h&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi94dWjlpTPAhWDNSYKHXtbAS8Q6AEIJjAC#v=onepage&q=c18%20polyyne%20c9h&f=false

Comment: @DavePhD I have no idea, I just used ChemSketch to draw it. You could draw it yourself.

Comment: ChemSketch is no good at all for drawing things like this.

Comment: @IvanNeretin C9h is 0.3 kcal/mol lower than D9h, has alternating bond angles of 157 and 163 degrees http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ja00120a026

Comment: Yeah, I got that. Like a cog wheel with nine asymmetric cogs, only the cogs are so small, and their asymmetry is smaller yet, so when you look at it, you pretty much see just a round wheel.